# PhpMyAdmin 4.6.6 OpenSSL error

Tags: phpmyadmin, openssl

At launch of PhpMyAdmin 4.6.6 under the access dialog box, there is:

```
OpenSSL error: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
```

With PHP 7.1.1 or 7.0.15 or 5.6.30.

Comment: Please provide your code. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also experiencing this.  Not a code.. its just visiting the phpmyadmin page prior to logging in.

Answer (score 5):

I confirm this is an issue on the upgrade, due to the cookie encryption. The error should disappear on the next login.

This will happen to users using openssl direcly (not via phpseclib) on upgrade.

See http://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/12924

Answer (score 3):

I encountered a similar openSSL error in phpMyAdmin. It's solved by fixing a misplaced bracket in the following library file.

```
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php
```

Line #613, Edited from this

```
|| (count($analyzed_sql_results[‘select_expr’] == 1)
```

to this

```
|| (count($analyzed_sql_results[‘select_expr’]) == 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be resolved by Updating phpmyadmin version to 4.9.1

Here is the link to manually upgrade PHPMyAdmin in ubuntu:
https://devanswers.co/manually-upgrade-phpmyadmin/

Comment: This tip worked better for me, as I was having a bunch of other errors. Also, keep in mind to check which phpMyAdmin version is best suited for you PHP version running in the server. Check before installing the automated version, so doesn´t need to upgrade afterwards.